# Woocommerce hook for order update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Good morning everyone.
As the title says I'm trying to fire a function when an order is updated.
More specifically I want to run this function when a custom field in the order page (admin side) is changed and then saved.

I'm not looking to find out when an order is complete or when its status is updated, but just when this field is updated.

Currently I'm using `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` hook but it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice?
Thank you!

-- EDIT --

`woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is the righ hook to use, I was having an error in the function triggered by this hook so if you ever need to run a function after you click update order in the admin page this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Might as well answer your own question then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written in the edit the `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is the right hook to use if you want to trigger a function or a response when an order is update.

Comment: Well, this was very close to what I'm needing. I'll keep looking. I need to find an action that I can connect to AFTER the order is updated, this is before.

Comment: @TheTC are you looking for a particular update? Like the order status or just a general update hook?

Comment: @Andrea I could use the order status.  This particular hook seems to trigger but then gets overwritten and the status hasn't changed.

Comment: nvm those are the standard ones.. https://gist.github.com/abegit/74e691d877cadc37d7b6 .. I didn't realize those triggered on every save, even if the status didn't change

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using the `save_post_shop_order` hook. It is called on the following events:

- order creation (both customer checkout process & admin)
- single order update
- bulk status update
- trashing the order
- untrashing the order

For watching only order updates, you have to filter out non-order type posts and post creations like so:

```php
add_action (
    'save_post_shop_order',
    function (int $postId, \WP_Post $post, bool $update): void
    {
        // Ignore order (post) creation
        if ($update !== true) {
            return;
        }

        // Here comes your code...
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

The `woocommerce_after_order_object_save` seemed to be a good choice first, but in my experience it **runs 3 times** on a single order update (in a simple, factory install without plugins). At the time of the first 2 runs, the order data wasn't even up to date (the status was the one before the update), so I find this hook useless.