# WooCommerce hook after order is updated?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Is there a hook I can use when I make a change to someone's order via the admin (such as their address, or a custom meta field)? I [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647343/woocommerce-hook-for-order-update) but unfortunately `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is fired before the order is saved, meaning I have no access to the newly updated data. What I need is to be able to use the new data that is saved to the order.

**UPDATE:** An issue with using `save_post_shop_order` is that the meta is updated before this is hit, so I can't compare the previously saved meta value, for example:

```
$metaArray = $_POST['meta'];

foreach($metaArray as $meta => $key) {
    $metaArr[$key["key"]] = $key["value"];
}

$meta = get_post_meta($order->ID);

if($meta['coverstart'][0] != $metaArr['coverstart']) {
    die("COVER START DATE HAS CHANGED");
}
```

The `die()` is never hit, because the script always gets the newly saved value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce hook for order update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647343/woocommerce-hook-for-order-update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` is fired **after the order is saved**… See this extract source code located in [`WC_Checkout` `create_order()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#339):

```
// Save the order.
$order_id = $order->save(); // <== Order is saved here before

do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data ); <== // The hook

return $order_id;
```

So in `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` you can **get the saved order data**:

- by retrieving the `WC_Order` object from the `$order_id` argument and using all methods on it.
- or using `get_post_meta()` on with the `$order_id` argument to get the data saved in `wp_postmeta` database table.

Then you can update the data with `update_post_meta()` function…

---

> You can even use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` before the data is saved…

You will be able to get the data from the `$order` argument using all available methods for the `WC_Order` class (CRUD getters methods).

You will be able to alter this data and saving it using the CRUD setters methods…

[Some examples in stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_checkout_create_order)

---

If you need to do that after the order process the hooks to be used can be:

- `woocommerce_new_order` (on newly created order event)
- `woocommerce_thankyou` (on order received page)
- `woocommerce_order_status_changed` (on order status changing event)

And may be some others…

---

To alter the data when order is saved in backend, you will use **`save_post_shop_order`** that has 3 arguments: `$post_id`, `$post` and `$update`…

Comment: What a fantastic answer. That makes a lot more sense to me now. Many thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Updated my question based on a problem using `save_post_shop_order`. @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LiamMcArthur You should make a new question with that update and roll back here to your initial question… Also try to add in that mew question some code that can be tested to be able to find out something useful for you…