# How to get updated WooCommerce order data?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can i get access to updated order data in this function? I am super confused.

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743727/10447197).

```
add_action ('save_post_shop_order',
function (int $postId, \WP_Post $post, bool $update): void{
    // Ignore order (post) creation
    if ($update !== true) {
        return;
    }

    // Here comes your code...
},10,3);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WORDPRESS HOOK**

If you want to run the function you can use the [**`edit_post_{$post->post_type}`**](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L4424) hook which is triggered only when a post is updated.

```
// run a function when the WooCommerce order is updated
add_action( 'edit_post_shop_order', 'edit_post_shop_order_callback', 99, 2 );
function edit_post_shop_order_callback( $post_ID, $post ) {

    // gets the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_ID );

    // get the data you want
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    $billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    // ...

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**WOOCOMMERCE HOOK**

Otherwise you could use the [**`woocommerce_update_order`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.173) WooCommerce hook.

```
// run a function when the WooCommerce order is updated
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'woocommerce_update_order_callback', 99, 1 );
function woocommerce_update_order_callback( $order_id ) {
    
    // gets the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // get the data you want
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    $billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    // ...

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [Woocommerce hook for order update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647343/woocommerce-hook-for-order-update)

Comment: And one more thing about " edit_post_shop_order " .. does it trigger if any third party plugin changes the order data programmatically ?  @Vincenzo Di Gaetano

Comment: The `edit_post_shop_order` hook is only triggered using one of these functions: `wp_update_post` and `wp_insert_post`. In the case of **wp_insert_post** it only works if the post already exists. While the hook will not trigger with the [CRUD methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/developing-using-woocommerce-crud-objects/) and with queries directly on the database.

Comment: "edit_post_shop_order" allows you to intervene and modify order data before it is saved, while "woocommerce_update_order" enables you to perform actions after the order has been saved and the changes are persistent in the database.